How to calculate the cross-correlation between two 2D numpy arrays along a given axis
Currently the SciPy's scipy.signal.correlate function supports computing the cross-correlation between two 1D arrays. However, there is no direct support for axis-wise cross-correlation between two 2D arrays of the same shape. For example, computing the cross-correlation between each row (or column) pair across two 2D arrays currently requires implementing a Python for loop. This limitation becomes frustrating when dealing with large datasets, as loops are computationally inefficient, and workarounds can be non-intuitive for many users.
Is there a way to add a parameter to scipy.signal.correlate (e.g., axis) that allows computation of axis-wise cross-correlation between two 2D arrays as shown in the example below
import numpy as np
from scipy.signal import correlate

# Two 2D arrays of the same shape
A = np.random.rand(1000, 100)
B = np.random.rand(1000, 100)

# Compute axis-wise cross-correlation along rows
result = correlate(A, B, axis=1, mode='full')


https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.correlate2d.html ?

You said that you have to write for loops in python. Can we see those for loops? For now, it is not clear to me what you mean by "axis-wise cross-correleation". It would help to see exactly what computation you want. And since you have a code to do it...
